# Python - Adding count to output

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerate

I'm writing a simple program that takes a number and continually doubles it until it has reached an upper limit. The code I've written does this with a for loop and while loop, but I want to add a count to the output to see how many iterations through the while loop it took to get to the upper limit.

The code looks like this:

```
def double_function():

print('Enter an upper range to target')
upper_range = int(input())

for number in range(0, upper_range):
    print('Enter a number to double')
    number = float(input())

    while number < upper_range:
        number * 2
        number += number
        print(number)
    else:
        break

output_list = list(str(number))
iterations = enumerate(output_list) 
print('It took ' + str(iterations) + ' iterations to reach ' + str(number))

double_function()
```

If upper_range = 1000 and number = 1, output is:

```
2.0
4.0
8.0
16.0
32.0
64.0
128.0
256.0
512.0
1024.0
It took <enumerate object at 0x7ffe02f74e40> iterations to reach 1024.0
```

I tried using **enumerate** because that's the only suggestion I've seen, but every other example used it with lists. I tried converting my output to a list, but I'm still not getting the output I want. I want it to look something like this:

```
1: 2.0
2: 4.0
3: 8.0
4: 16.0
5: 32.0
6: 64.0
7: 128.0
8: 256.0
9: 512.0
10: 1024.0
It took 10 iterations to reach 1000
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try reading [the documentation for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) `enumerate`, which includes an example of common usage? Do you understand what it's for?

Comment: You want to only know the total amount iterations it took to get to the limit ? then just add a variable and += it in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate` returns an enumerate object see `help(enumerate)`.

<s>To get what you're looking for, just use `len(output_list)`</s>

Just realized your "`output_list`" isn't actually a list containing the intermediate results. So to actually get the number of iterations, you can just initialize a counter before starting the `while` loop, then increment it by one in the `while`-loop block, and once it breaks, that variable will store the number of iterations performed.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED. Initialized a counter before starting `while` loop and incremented by one inside the loop. Code looks like this:

```
def double_function():

print('Enter an upper range to target')
upper_range = int(input())

for number in range(0, upper_range):
    print('Enter a number to double')
    number = float(input())

    iterations = 0
    while number < upper_range:
        number * 2
        number += number
        iterations += 1
        print(iterations, number)
    else:
        break
print('It took ' + str(iterations) + ' iterations to reach ' + str(number))

double_function()
```

Output if upper_range = 1000, number = 1:

```
1 2.0
2 4.0
3 8.0
4 16.0
5 32.0
6 64.0
7 128.0
8 256.0
9 512.0
10 1024.0
It took 10 iterations to reach 1024.0
```

Comment: quick tip on string formatting, as of 3.6, Python has this feature called f-strings, which would allow you to clean up your `print` call to `print(f'It took {iterations} iterations to reach {number}')`